# C wrapper for C++ Library, problems with iostream and gcc

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I want to use this C++ Library in C-Code (and compile the code with gcc):
https://github.com/fairlight1337/libcflie

To do that I added Wrapper functions to CCrazyflie.h, CCrazyflie.cpp, CCrazyRadio.h and CCrazyRadio.cpp (all functions I want to use are in those Files):

Added to CCrazyRadio.h:

```
extern "C"
{
  CCrazyRadio* newCCrazyRadio(string strRadioID);
  void deleteCCrazyRadio(CCrazyRadio* cr);
  int CCrazyRadio_startRadio(CCrazyRadio* cr);
}
```

Added to CCrazyRadio.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
   CCrazyRadio* newCCrazyRadio(string strRadioID) {return new CCrazyRadio(strRadioID);}
   void deleteCCrazyRadio(CCrazyRadio* cr) {delete cr;}
   int CCrazyRadio_startRadio(CCrazyRadio* cr) {if(cr->startRadio()) return 1; else return 0;}
}
```

I did the same thing for the functions in CCrazyflie.h and CCrazyflie.cpp.

I can use the wrappers in C-code and they work when compiled with g++, but when compiling with gcc the compiler complains that it doesn't know iostream (included in CCrazyflie.h and CCrazyRadio.h which are both included in my C-code).

Am I doing this right? How can I make gcc find iostream (and the other C++ libraries that are included)?
If needed I would be happy to show you more of the code, I just tried to keep the post short.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Regards,
Daniel

Comment: You have to compile the wrappers with a C++ compiler. C compilers do not compile C++ code.

Comment: i think the best way is to compile the wrapper in a .lib and link to that. also provide the library with a plain `c` interface.

Comment: g++ is the gnu c++ compiler while gcc is the gnu c compiler. So it's correct that a c compiler (gcc) doesn't accept c++ code

Comment: A C interface for a function taking a `std::string` as a parameter isn't going to work like you think, regardless of anything else.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I did compile the library (including the wrappers) with g++, giving me with libcflie.a and the two headers to use. But when compiling my C-code including those headers with gcc, I get the problem described.

Comment: You're wondering why a C compiler cannot compile the C++ standard library? Really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really. This is what's wrong with software development, (not only) these days.

Comment: @user3477950: A widespread lack of common sense? Yes, I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, I am not wondering. I am aware that it can't work this way and I am asking how to do it in a way that gcc doesn't try to compile c++ libraries. I know I didn't describe the issue particularly well (I added missing information in the comments below), sorry about that!

Comment: @Fr4nky: Okay then :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the linker as some have suggested, or that the wrappers need to be compiled with a C++ compiler (although they do).

The issue is that the C file includes the header that defines the wrappers, and the wrapper functions take types that the C language doesn't have - eg string. The `extern` statement tells the C++ compiler not to mangle the names, but doesn't magically make anything inside legal C.

So, your wrapper functions need to be defined to take C types, so your

```
CCrazyRadio* newCCrazyRadio(string strRadioID);
```

becomes something like

```
CCrazyRadio* newCCrazyRadio(char * radioId);
```

And internally to newCCrazyRadio you can construct a `string` to hold your radioID, if needed. If `CCrazyRadio` is a class, you will still have troubles though. So, if this is just being returned as some sort of handle, you could perhaps replace with a `void*`

You still need the `extern 'C'`.

You will also need to ensure that the header containing the wrapper functions ONLY includes C header files. Even if gcc (in C mode) can find them, they will not contain valid C code. This means it cannot include iostream etc.

One further thing, I recall that C doesnt understand the `extern C` syntax, so you may need to wrap that with a conditional compiliation block eg (you will need to check the syntax your self)

```
#ifdef _CPLUSPLUS_ // Check this bit
extern 'C'
{
#endif
//Put your prototype wrappers here

#ifdef _CPLUSPLUS
}
#endif
```

This basically means that only the C++ compiler will see the `extern C` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will do that. But as far as I understand this doesn't solve the problem with iostream not being found by gcc, right?

Comment: Not directly. You dont post enough of your code, or the error message to be certain, but I expect it is complaining when you compile the C code.

Comment: I uploaded all of my code and the libcflie here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1499686/aerial_gcc.zip

Comment: I think gcc complains that it doesn't even find the header. On my system iostream resides in /lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/iostream, which is probably not in gcc's include path (but in g++'s).

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thanks for the help! The working code is uploaded here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1499686/aerial_gcc.zip
Unfortunately I can only mark one of the two answers as accepted although both were helpful :-(

Comment: But...But... This is the better answer :-) In fact, the other answer is just wrong.